# Insert a link in a translated message wicket apache

Tags: java, wicket

I am working on a small task with an old wicket Apache version 1.4.x

that task is to add a text to one page, but that text should be translated for many languages, and it has a link :

You are logged in with limited functionality - please [sign the agreement](https://www.yahoo.com) for full access

so is there is a way to pass the link in the message ?

Comment: You can nest wicket components inside wicket:message tags. See: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Wicket%27s+XHTML+tags#Wicket'sXHTMLtags-Elementwicket:message

Answer (score 2):

I guess the Agreement page has a static url, so just hardcode the link in the message.

```
 <wicket:message key="someKey" escape="false" />
```

MyApp.properties

```
 someKey=You are logged in with limited functionality - please <a href="some/url">sign the agreement</a> for full access
```

MyApp_de.properties

```
 someKey=(in German) You are logged in with limited functionality - please <a href="some/url">sign the agreement</a> for full access
```